# Does any one know how to delete CACHE Memory of the browser using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I don't want to delete Cookies of the Browser, because it will lead me to Logout my account, so can any one tell me how to delete CACHE Memory of the browser?

Comment: Testng is a testing framework not something that deals with the browser.

Comment: @niharika_neo you mean testng doesnt have a handle with browser. Then how automation testing on website is done with testng ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot clear the cache, but you can ask that your pages will not be cached when your page loads in the header.

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
```